# JPA Relation between classes, referring to their Interfaces

Tags: java, jpa

I have two classes with their respective interfaces between which I want to create a JPA `@OneToOne` Relation. This fails with `[class EmployeeImpl] uses a non-entity [class Adress] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field adress]`.

First Interface / Class:

```
public interface Employee {
  public long getId();
  public Adress getAdress();
  public void setAdress(Adress adress);
}

@Entity(name = "EmployeeImpl")
@Table(name = "EmployeeImpl")
public class EmployeeImpl implements Employee {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "employeeId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Adress adress;

  // snip, getters and setters
}
```

Second Interface / Class:

```
public interface Adress {
  public long getId();
  public String getStreet();
  public void setStreet(String street);
}

@Entity(name = "AdressImpl")
@Table(name = "AdressImpl")
public class AdressImpl implements Adress {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "AdressId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "Street")
  private String street;

  // Snip getters and setters
}
```

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="employee"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>EmployeeImpl</class>
        <class>AdressImpl</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name"
    value="create-matterhorn-employee.jdbc" />
            <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" 
    value="drop-matterhorn-employee.jdbc" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I shortened out package names and imports and such. Exception occurs when trying to create the EntityManagerFactory (where you hand over the persistence unit). I am using eclipse link 2.0.2.

Comment: Well it is normal, you cannot do that. `EmployeeImpl` should contain a reference to `AdressImpl`

Comment: Entity reference should be given in another entity while defining. In your case it is AddressImpl and not the interface Address

Comment: Problem is, interface and class are in two different OSGi bundles. The interface `Employee` cannot see `AdressImpl`. So how do go about this?

Comment: I believe `@OneToOne(targetEntity = AddressImpl.class)` will do the trick

Comment: Jep. @Osw answer is correct. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually JPA does allow such interface relationships, but in this case you have to provide an entity class implementing the interface, in you case this will look as follows:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = AddressImpl.class)
private Adress adress;
```

Comment: I think the point made by the other answer is that the JPA spec does NOT cater for it (when it lists types of fields accepted by JPA there is no reference to it, nor under relation annotations). All you're doing here is restricting a field to be that particular implementation, which is not the same as allowing interface relationships ... an interface could have multiple implementations clearly, as supported by some implementations. There's a difference

Comment: @Neil, formally you're right, JPA allows interface notations, still requiring an entity class. I've edited my answer slightly while you've been typing your comment.

Comment: Both answers correct, this one in my case more helpful. Accepting this and hoping it will help others too.

Answer (score 2):

JPA standard does not allow for interface fields (or Collection of interface fields) being entity relationships. Some JPA implementations do support it (e.g DataNucleus JPA), but its a vendor extension to the spec. Consequently you either use one of those implementations or change your model (or add extra annotations/XML to define what type is actually stored there).